# Add the inquiry number into the enquiry form email subject (entity forms)

Tags: emails, entities

The emails that come from the enquiry form on my drupal website have the exact subject and it's difficult to sort through the enquries.

I have the enquiry form set up using entity forms and rules. I just don't know how to add the inquiry number to the subject.

Looking through the database of enquiries, they do have a number associated

Thanks

Comment: Can you enhance (edit) your question by including more details about the rule you have created so far (ideally in rules export format, pasted into your question somehow). That may help to provide an answer to your (interesting) question ...